# Смена изображения, пока открыт список

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. Как сделать следующее. При нажатии на div в котором есть тег img, в котором зеленая кнопка, при её активности она меняется на оранжевую и стрелка перевернута вниз (изображение есть).

```
<li>
    <div id="jot-1" class="jotting-name"><img src="images/jot-green.png">
        <span>Хотите иметь красивую улыбку? Приходите в клинику «Гармония»!</span>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div class="jotting-detail" style="display: none" id="jot-2">
        Стоматологическая клиника "Гармония" стабильно развивается на рынке стоматологических услуг Краснодара уже 15 лет. Руководство стоматологической клиники "Гармония" с уважением относится к своим сотрудникам, создавая каждому необходимые условия для повышения уровня квалификации и профессионального роста. Благодаря отличной работе коллектива клиники "Гармония" успешно осуществляется оказание стоматологических услуг высокого качества! Стоматологическая клиника "Гармония" оказывает весь спектр стоматологических услуг.

        Ценовая политика клиники рассчитана на потребителя со средним уровнем дохода.<br><br><br>

        <span class="orange"><b>НАШИ ЦЕЛИ В ОБЛАСТИ КАЧЕСТВА:</b></span><br><br>

        • превзойти ожидания Пациентов, удовлетворив все их требования в сфере стоматологических услуг<br><br>

        • постоянно повышать качество выполняемых работ <br><br>

        • контролировать качество расходных материалов и технического оборудования<br><br>

        • осваивать новые методики и технологии, позволяющие добиваться гарантированных результатов лечения<br><br>

        • поощрять лучших сотрудников<br><br>

        • совершенствовать управление предприятием и качество услуг

    </div>
    <script>
        $("#jot-1").click(function () {
            $("#jot-2").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    </script>
</li>
```

Вот здесь оно верстается: http://default.blaze.su/jotting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте картинку фоном блока, например div-а, а еще лучше фоном псевдоселектора `::after` для `div.jotting-name` и при нажатии меняйте класс соответствующего div-а, в css укажите стили для неактивного/активного блока с разным фоном.